# Loop through multidimensional array, split and write results to file

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm trying to generate separate documents based on data stored in a MySQL database.

**The table structure:**

```
+----+-------+-----+------+-------+
| id | order | qty | item | total |
+----+-------+-----+------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |   1 | AAAA |    10 |
|  2 |     2 |   1 | AAAA |    20 |
|  3 |     2 |   1 | BBBB |       |
|  4 |     2 |   1 | EEEE |       |
+----+-------+-----+------+-------+
```

*Note: values for column total are only on the 'parent' row*

The desired output would look like this..
**For single row results, a XML file containing:**

```
<Order>1</Order>
<Total>10</Total>
<Detail>
 <Qty>1</Qty>
 <Item>AAAA</Item>
</Detail>
```

**For multiple row results, a (separate) file containing:**

```
<Order>2</Order>
<Total>20</Total>
<Detail>
 <Qty>1</Qty>
 <Item>AAAA</Item>
</Detail>
<Detail>
 <Qty>1</Qty>
 <Item>BBBB</Item>
</Detail>
<Detail>
 <Qty>1</Qty>
 <Item>EEEE</Item>
</Detail>
```

First thing I did was to fetch the data in a multidimensional array:

```
$ordersArray = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$getOrders = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($getOrders, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  foreach ($rows as $value) {
    $ordersArray[$value['order']][] = $value;
  }
```

or the equivalent of:

```
$ordersArray = array(
 1 => array(array('id' => '1', 'order' => '1', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'AAAA', 'total' => '10')),
 2 => array(array('id' => '2', 'order' => '2', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'BBBB', 'total' => '20'), array('id' => '3', 'order' => '2', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'CCCCC', 'total' => ''), array('id' => '4', 'order' => '2', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'EEEE', 'total' => '')),
 );
```

I manage to output the desired files as long as they contain only one row, using:

```
foreach($ordersArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        foreach($subvalue as $k => $v) {
            $fileName = $subvalue['order'].".txt";
            $output  = '';
            $output .= "<Order>".$subvalue['order']."</Order>\n";
            $output .= "<Total>".$subvalue['total']."</Total>\n";
            $output .= "<Details>\n";
            $output .= "<Item>".$subvalue['item']."</Item>\n";
            $output .= "<Quantity>".$subvalue['qty']."</Quantity>\n";
            $output .= "</Details>\n";
        }
            file_put_contents($fileName, $output);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<Order>1</Order>
<Total>10</Total>
<Details>
<ProductSKU>AAAAA<ProductSKU>
<Quantity>1<Quantity>
</Details>
```

BUT when an order has multiple lines, it only outputs a single entry. 
**What should I do to make sure all items linked to a specific order are grouped and written to the same file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a for loop to muchin xour code and you need a marker to get only the first order and  Total. The tag Order1 u added to get a valid xml code.

```
<?php
$ordersArray = array(
 1 => array(array('id' => '1', 'order' => '1', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'AAAA', 'total' => '10')),
 2 => array(array('id' => '2', 'order' => '2', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'BBBB', 'total' => '20'), array('id' => '3', 'order' => '2', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'CCCCC', 'total' => ''), array('id' => '4', 'order' => '2', 'qty' => '1', 'item' => 'EEEE', 'total' => '')),
 );
$output  = '';
foreach($ordersArray as $key => $value) {
    $output  .= "<Order1>";
    $n = 0;
    $output  = '';
    foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {

            $fileName = $subvalue['order'].".txt";

            IF($n == 0 )
            {   
                $n = 1;
                $output .= "<Order>".$subvalue['order']."</Order>\n";
                $output .= "<Total>".$subvalue['total']."</Total>\n";                                
            }
            $output .= "<Details>\n";
            $output .= "<Item>".$subvalue['item']."</Item>\n";
            $output .= "<Quantity>".$subvalue['qty']."</Quantity>\n";
            $output .= "</Details>\n";
        }
    $output  .= "<Order1>";
    file_put_contents($fileName, $output);
}
new dBug($output); 
?>
```

Comment: thank you for helping out,.. it sure is a step in the right direction, except the [generated output](https://pastebin.com/fRLh6K3w) for the second order also contains the data from the first + <Order> and <Total> are repeated for each item,.. I only need them once before details of each item are displayed.

Comment: i tested this code on phpfiddle and it works https://pastebin.com/jkENxSUA

Comment: Can you show your complte code, there seems to be the part of $n missing

Comment: this is the [complete code](https://pastebin.com/v8ryEPGu) I did add line 25 to create the actual .txt files

Comment: the $n = 0  is at the wrong line it has to be before the second for loop sorry

Comment: Yes, that removed the duplicate <Order> and <Total> tags when the order contains multiple items.. However, content of the first order is still included in the [second file](https://pastebin.com/dyLTXrCk)

Comment: I edited my answer, this would now created for every order a new file. and you see i changed the position of $ouput = ''; so that a new text us formed and not as before all text combined in $output

Comment: Works like a charm! Thnx for the help @nbk